# Mechanics diagnosis of overheating problem

Tags: jeep, coolant-leak

My daughter in law took her Jeep in because it was overheating. Jeep dealer told her it was the thermostat and also that the overflow was leaking onto the radiator and that because of that her radiator needs to be replaced. Has anyone ever heard of this being an issue? They gave her a list of things wrong with this 2 year old lease and want to charge $2000.00 for a brake job and fixing this overheating problem. Something seems wrong to me. The radiator replacement is what’s really got me suspicious of their diagnosis of problems

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this a lease on a new vehicle? Does the vehicle still have a warranty?

Comment: What year and model of Jeep? If this vehicle is under lease, I would make sure to read the lease to see what repairs are covered by the warranty and/or lease. That seems expensive. Was the $2,000 to take care of everything on the list, or just the brakes?

Answer (score 2):

I'd certainly need a better explanation as to why the radiator needed to be replaced.  Coolant leaking onto something isn't going to ruin it - especially something that is specifically designed to hold coolant. The radiator cap and overflow system are designed to limit the pressure of the system so nothing bursts, so that shouldn't be it either.

Sometimes techs oversimplify the reasons, and sometimes people that don't understand the "jargon" simply misunderstand what's really being said.  Get a better description of the problem and the work to be performed.  If it doesn't make sense, get a second opinion from another dealer or shop.

But also, why is any of this even a concern on a 2 year old lease?  Is the thermostat and cooling system not covered by the warranty?  One of the attractive points of mosts leases is not having to worry about repairs.

Comment: 100% correct! Per [their warranty](https://www.jeep.com/crossbrand/warranty/pdf/99GenericCoverage.pdf) the whole power train is covered for 3y/36k miles... so why are they trying to charge anything!? Unless you’re already over 36k miles...

Comment: @kyle_engineer, and if they are on year two of a lease and already at 36k, year three is going to be very expensive!

Comment: She isn’t over her miles. My son is trying to find out more info as to why they need a new radiator. He keeps getting the run around and won’t return his phone calls. Just seems odd the explanation they gave her. Thank you for your help.